# Do i need to install crypto module from npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-crypto

I am making use of crypto module in my app. 
It seems like there is crypto module distributed in nodejs http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html
so do i need to do npm install crypto? what is the difference from https://npmjs.org/package/crypto and nodejs api crypto modules?

Comment: The npm package does all the calculations with JavaScript. The crypto module that comes with node does afaik most of the calculation with a C/C++ module. The npm version could be useful if you have node installation without the crypto module (e.g. `libssl` not installed.)

Comment: Thanks it could be may be answer to my question. you made it clear. thank you

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using the methods from the Crypto module that comes with NodeJS, i.e. those described on http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html then no, you do not need to do `npm install crypto`.

Comment: Are there any differences in these two modules. both look very similar .

Comment: The "official" module is a lot more comprehensive. From what I can tell, there is nothing in the unofficial module that isn't in the official one. What is it you are using the module for?

Comment: I am using it to create hmac signature. So official module is fine i think. Was just confused to see same module in npm.

Comment: `import {} from "crypto";` or `require("crypto")`